# How can I remove duplicate lines from 1 TB of data in a directory and all subsequent sub-directories?

Tags: python, sort

I need to remove duplicate lines from about a TB or so of text files contained within a directory and various sub-directories of that directory.

I've tried stuff like using sort -u *.txt > newfile.txt and creating a simple python script from the following

[Remove duplicate lines from multiple files in a folder: Check only files within a range](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326330/remove-duplicate-lines-from-multiple-files-in-a-folder-check-only-files-within/326356#326356?newreg=3869de8a340f4fcfaa6484d6b4e91006)

Neither seemed to work and sort -u just ran my laptop out of memory (32gb) when trying to process a nearly 100gb folder of text files.

Comment: The sort command isn't supposed to run out of RAM FWIW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930044/how-could-the-unix-sort-command-sort-a-very-large-file maybe there's a parameter possible like --buffer-size or something...

Comment: Can you tell us how those dupe-lines are organized in your files ? Are they successive lines or repeated randomly within a single file, or across distinct files ? Thinking about any useful suggestion requires a trifle more details... Oh, and are those files flat text ? and should the output preserve the original order of lines in each file (minus the deleted dupes of course) ? Answer with @Cbhihe if you will.